# Download report content with ansible from Cisco DNA Center

Tags: ansible, cisco

I have an inventory report which is generated every day on our Cisco DNA Center. I would like to download this report with ansible to my ansible control node.

My playbook so far is:

```yaml
---
- hosts: DNA
  vars_files:
    - /root/ansible/credentials.yaml
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
  
  - name: Get all Reports
    cisco.dnac.reports_executions_info:
      dnac_host: "{{dnac_host}}"
      dnac_username: "{{dnac_username}}"
      dnac_password: "{{dnac_password}}"
      dnac_verify: "{{dnac_verify}}"
      dnac_port: "{{dnac_port}}"
      dnac_version: "{{dnac_version}}"
      dnac_debug: "{{dnac_debug}}"
      reportId: a13236797-7a85-4774-98bd-552b41a3s5v7
      headers:
        custom: text/csv
      saveFile: true
      dirPath: /root/ansible/outputs
    register: result
        
  - name: debug
    debug: 
     msg: "{{ result.dnac_response }}"
```

In the documentation for this module it tells the following:

*Returns report content.
Save the response to a file by converting the response data as a blob and setting the file format available from content-disposition response header.*

https://github.com/cisco-en-programmability/dnacenter-ansible/blob/main/plugins/modules/reports_executions_info.py

Is this a misunderstanding from my side? I just want to transfer the generated report from the DNAC machine to my ansible machine.

Comment: What isn't working as expected exactly ? Do you get any errors ? From the [documentation](https://cisco-en-programmability.github.io/dnacenter-ansible/main/plugins/reports_executions_info_module.html), you should get a report inside the folder given as `dirPath` on your controller. Since this is a rather specific collection keeping its documentation out of the usual ansible doc tree, I suggest you file a bug in their issue tracker on github.

Comment: Since that module uses their sdk, this is apparently the function that is used to save the file https://github.com/cisco-en-programmability/dnacentersdk/blob/96864c631f5bcb7c55e3ece9f47136814528512d/dnacentersdk/api/v2_2_2_3/reports.py#L399 (switch to the corresponding api version if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executionID was missing, thats why the content wasn't downloaded. There were no errors thats why it was confusing to me.